# ESCAPE SEQUENCE IN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to do a where by clause on my table to find the exact string match in my table
it works fine in the following scenario

```
declare @issuerName varchar(max)
set @issuerName = 'WIDEOPENWEST FINANCE, LLC'

select * 
from company 
where ParentName = @issuerName
```

but fails for the following query

```
declare @issuerName varchar(max)
set @issuerName = 'TOYS 'R' US, INC'

select * 
from company 
where ParentName = @issuerName
```

because of the single quotes.

Could someone let me know what it would be the best way to tackle it since single quotes can appear any where in the string? I tried adding single quotes around this variable but it doesn't work.

```
set @issuerName = ''TOYS 'R' US, INC''
```

Comment: double those single quotes !

Answer (score 5):

You'd do this:

```
set @issuerName = 'TOYS ''R'' US, INC'
```

Putting the escaped `'` within the string itself.

Further, if you need to change the escaped character as with a `LIKE` clause you may want to check out the `ESCAPE` keyword which lets you change the character used for the current query.  Please see [Using [] and ESCAPE clause in SQL Server LIKE query](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainala/archive/2008/08/17/using-and-escape-clause-in-sql-server-like-query.aspx).

Comment: the single quotes can appear any where in the string so i can handle in that case.should i do a replace first for single quotes to double quotes in the whole string

Comment: If the data is already in a variable or coming from another column you don't need to escape them. You only have to escape quotes if you're writing a string literal as in your example above.